# How to update AutocompleteTextView predictions with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-adapter, autocompletetextview

Three days have passed, still stuck, please help.

**Problem**: Using google getAutocompletePredictions I cannot seems to update the AutocompleteTextView.

My custom adapter Filter and getView part:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                mResultList = new ArrayList<>();
                // Query the autocomplete API for the entered constraint
                mResultList.clear();
                mResultList = getGooglePredictions(constraint.toString());
                if (mResultList != null) {
                    // Results
                    results.values = mResultList;
                    results.count = mResultList.size();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                Log.d("ACP_RESULT", "API returned at least one result, update data");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    PlaceAutocomplete item = getItem(position);
    TextView newView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address_entry));
    newView.setText(item.toString());
    return convertView;
}
```

I get the predictions but they are not updated + when clicked on them I get error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. ...

My activity part:

```
addressPredictionAdapter = new PredictionsAdapter(Landing.this, mGoogleApiClient, mAutoCompleteFilter,mBounds);
    address_text.setThreshold(THRESHOLD);
    address_text.setAdapter(addressPredictionAdapter);

    address_text.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            PlaceAutocomplete book = (PlaceAutocomplete) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            address_text.setText(book.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out after the fourth day. Oh the productivity of beginners :D
So the code above is all correct but the fault was in the `getGooglePredictions(String userInput)` method where is just added to the methods return `ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete>` variable and never emptyed it.